# Typescript compilation error: <x> is not assignable to type <y>

Tags: typescript

When I am trying to assign

```
let blob:Blob = {blobParts: [content]};
```

where content is a json.

where `Blob` is declared in `lib.d.ts` as

```
  interface Blob {
      readonly size: number;
      readonly type: string;
      msClose(): void;
      msDetachStream(): any;
      slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
  }

  declare var Blob: {
    prototype: Blob;
    new (blobParts?: any[], options?: BlobPropertyBag): Blob;
  };
```

it is giving me the following error:

```
Type '{ blobParts: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Blob'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'blobParts' does not exist in type 'Blob'.
```

I have verified the spelling of blobParts a number of times

Answer (score 0):

You should construct Blob with `new` keyword...

```
let blob: Blob = new Blob([content]);
```

Comment: I believe interfaces donot require constructing this way. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: using let blob: Blob = new Blob([content]) I get                 
ReferenceError: Blob is not defined

Comment: [It should work...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20content%20%3D%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20blob%3A%20Blob%20%3D%20new%20Blob(%5Bcontent%5D)%3B) What's your enviroment?

Comment: typescipt:^2.2.1 with es5